# Decode url-like strings much quicker

Tags: regex, python-3.x, urllib

I have several GB of data encoded in different xml files. For some reasons, the (closed source) program generating these xml files encode the text with an url-like representation, e.g. `'08.06.2016 22:41:35'` becomes `08%2E06%2E2016%2022%3A41%3A35`

There are mostly spaces, (decimal) dots and colon in the data I am interested in but I need to keep the code open to any kind of hex representation.

For now, I am using `urllib.parse.unquote`. It is however very slow: using profiler I found out that 90% of the time spent by my data mining algorithm is due to `urllib.parse.unquote`. You can see below how it compares with replace.

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
from time import clock

t0=clock()
for i in range(10000):
    unquote('08%2E06%2E2016')
t1=clock()   

t2=clock()
for i in range(10000):
    '08%2E06%2E2016'.replace('%2E','\x2E')
t3=clock()

print('unquote time: ',t1-t0,'\nreplace time: ',t3-t2)
```

> unquote time:  0.12173581222984353
>
> replace time: 0.009713842143412421

I could try to chain all the hex I know with replace, but I'm still afraid to miss something.
I have tried to use `re.sub` or similar but I was unsuccessfull : it is not so trivial to replace '%' by '\x'.

Any idea?

I'm using Python 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it can be done *much* quicker in pure Python, but `unquote_to_bytes` gives about 2x speedup on my machine:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote_to_bytes
unquote_to_bytes('08%2E06%2E2016').decode()
```

Comment: This partly answered my question as it divides by 2 the duration. If no better answer comes up, I will upgrade it to "answered". thanks, it's already a good result :)

Comment: To accelerate the processus, it is better to do unquote_to_bytes on the whole XML once than doing it for each line we want to extract.